# jQuery Function exists but not bound to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm having very odd behavior with a jQuery plugin `royalSlider`. I know that at run time the function exists and is in the jQuery object.

```
console.info(jQuery.fn.royalSlider);
//function (b){var f=arguments;return this.each(function(){var =l(this);if("object"===typeof ||!b)c.data("royalSlider")||c.data("royalSlider",new (c,b));else if((c=c.data("royalSlider"))&&c[b])return [b].apply(c,Array.prototype.slice.call(f,1))})}
```

However running directly under this console.info `royalSlider` function will return undefined:

```
$('#rsGallery').royalSlider(this.options);
//TypeError: $(...).royalSlider is not a function
```

How is it that `royalSlider` is on the `jQuery` object but not a `jQuery` selector?

Comment: Maybe `$ !== jQuery`.

Comment: I've also tried `jQuery('#rsGallery').royalSlider(this.options);`..... But I just doubled checked, you are correct... I'm disappointed in myself, I've let my family and wife down...

Comment: Do you want to add that as an answer Felix? Rather you than me